# Problems with CORS + Angularjs + Bearer Token + WebApi

Tags: angularjs, iis, cors

I'm having problems trying to connect to a webapi with angular.
I have been reading all day about different problems and possible solutions, but still can't make it work.

Things I'm doing:

Server side, I set this on my web.config

```
<system.webServer>    
    <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://localhost:53775" />
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="accept, authorization, user" />
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, OPTIONS" />
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />      
        </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

Which sends the right headers on the response as you will see below

From the angular side:

I configure my app

dashboardApp.config(function ($sceDelegateProvider, $httpProvider) {

```
$httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;

$sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist([
  'self',      
  'http://localhost:50561/**']);
```

});

And finally I make the query from localhost:53775 (mvc app) to localhost:50561 (webapi)

```
var url = webStorage.get('webapi');
var deferred = $q.defer();
$http.get(url, {
    withCredentials: true,
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + webStorage.get('token'),
        'User': webStorage.get('user')
    }}).success(deferred.resolve)
    .error(deferred.reject);

return deferred.promise;
```

The result in Chrome and Firefox is the following:

```
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:8888
Request URL:http://localhost:50561/api/Values
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:400 Bad Request
Request Headersview source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,es-419;q=0.6,es;q=0.4
Access-Control-Request-Headers:accept, authorization, user
Access-Control-Request-Method:GET
Cookie:__utma=1.957086229.1399375527.1401957296.1401963654.14; __utmz=1.1399375527.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); ASP.NET_SessionId=034dzycm0wtqagt1ftihfwje;.ASPXAUTH=B654AD08FADA17AF59A3C57C883D1E33720A7874F5F0155A65DDA202AAA296DE08E8A1ED5F3D6729B9C8D69AF1DB584300E6D9136E410F717801051E805F1A1AB0D28245917E7482E232EBD807BF007C48609B8347FC9812D4695C57722498B0545CFE9257C001245566C46D5EABC00043B822AEB031526B18CB338214CAB7ACC7D4262183B2B8A742FA115447124D34; XSRF-TOKEN=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJzZWxmIiwiYXVkIjoiaHR0cDovL2xvY2FsaG9zdDo1MDU2MSIsIm5iZiI6MTQwMjQxNzA3NiwiZXhwIjoxNDAyNDE3MTk2LCJ1bmlxdWVfbmFtZSI6Im9wdGlvcCIsInJvbGUiOiJvcHRpb3AifQ.9T6sgI9Mv6YAWT8pDW4TDBhlWZoEFmIRLV0dh7rRpBU
Host:localhost:50561
Origin:http://localhost:53775
Proxy-Connection:keep-alive
Referer:http://localhost:53775/DashBoard
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.114 Safari/537.36


Response Headers  view source

Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:accept, authorization, user
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET, POST, PUT, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://localhost:53775
Cache-Control:no-cache
Content-Length:65
Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8
Date:Tue, 10 Jun 2014 16:18:10 GMT
Expires:-1
Pragma:no-cache
Server:Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-AspNet-Version:4.0.30319
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
X-SourceFiles:=?UTF-8?B?QzpcV29ya3NwYWNlXEdpdGh1YlxkYXJpb2dyaWZmb1xvcHRpb3BcU2VydmljZXNcV2ViQXBpXGFwaVxFdmFsdWF0aW9uc1xHZXRQZXJmb3JtZWRFdmFsdWF0aW9uc1wzNg==?=
```

Now, I'm completely out of ideas, since the iisexpress is sending the response with the requeried fields for CORS.

Comment: Are you using the routes from angular js?

Comment: I have added the js but I'm not using them explicitly

Comment: And also added them as module of my app

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you have CORS attribute already enabled you donot need the custom header on the web.config

```
      public static class WebApiConfig
      {
          public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
          {

      var enableCorsAttribute = new EnableCorsAttribute("http://yourdomain.com",
                                               "Origin, Content-Type, Accept",
                                               "GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS");
      config.EnableCors(enableCorsAttribute);
```

Comment: I don't have the reputation to vote up your answer
What did I do?
On my web config I removed the 
`system.webServer><httpProtocol><customHeaders> </....`
section.

Added this on the Global.Asax
`var allowedMethods = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["cors:allowedMethods"];
            var allowedOrigin = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["cors:allowedOrigin"];
            var allowedHeaders = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["cors:allowedHeaders"];
            var attr = new EnableCorsAttribute(allowedOrigin, allowedHeaders, allowedMethods);            
            config.EnableCors(attr);`

Comment: And added this in web.config
`<system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
    <remove name="WebDAVModule"/>
  </modules>
  <handlers>
    <remove name="WebDAV" />
  </handlers>
</system.webServer>`
Again, thanks so much for you help, and will bookmark this, so ASAP I get the reputation will vote up this answer.